# Javascript absolute path to URL works on one page, but creates ajax error message on another

Tags: javascript, url, http-status-code-404

I have two URLs:

http://s140452.gridserver.com/view-pullsheet/

https://s140452.gridserver.com/locations/

When browsing through any properties on the locations page (as well as any single property, filtering properties using the sidebar, adding and removing properties from the "pullsheet") the jcart.js script works fine -- it is in control of adding and removing photos from the "pullsheet".

From this page however, http://s140452.gridserver.com/view-pullsheet/ , I get the following error "Ajax error: Edit the path in jcart.js to fix".

The code in question is:

```
    var path = 'https://s140452.gridserver.com/wp-content/themes/re/assets/functions/jcart',
        container = $('#jcart'),
        token = $('[name=jcartToken]').val(),
        tip = $('#jcart-tooltip');

    var config = (function() {
        var config = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: path + '/config-loader.php',
            data: {
                "ajax": "true"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                config = response;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Ajax error: Edit the path in jcart.js to fix.');
            }
        });
        return config;
    }());
```

How can the script be working fine on the locations page but throw an error from a different URL? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

jcart.js is located @ https://s140452.gridserver.com/wp-content/themes/re/assets/js/jcart.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are running into the same origin problem. https vs http

```
var path = 'https://s140452.gridserver.com/wp-content/themes/re/assets/functions/jcart',
```

to

```
var path = '//s140452.gridserver.com/wp-content/themes/re/assets/functions/jcart',
```

Comment: What would be the right way to write that path as a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

With your error function you are assuming that the error can only be the incorrect path. Why not implement the function as `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` (see [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), put a breakpoint in that function and then find out the true error.