# jQuery doesn't work in FF or IE but works fine in Chrome

Tags: java, jquery, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working on a project were I'm using REST to communicate with the db, it generates XML code, example of how it looks below.

```
<ns2:MultipleResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v1_0.model.service.mydomain.com">
    <ns2:AttributeType>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <ns2:Name>Type of Address</ns2:Name>
        <ns2:Definition>Definition for Type of Address</ns2:Definition>
        <ns2:DataType>ShortText</ns2:DataType>
        <ns2:MultipleSelect>false</ns2:MultipleSelect>
        <ns2:AttributeGroupType>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <ns2:Name>Address</ns2:Name>
            <ns2:Code>ADR</ns2:Code>
            <ns2:Definition>Definition of Address</ns2:Definition>
        </ns2:AttributeGroupType>
    </ns2:AttributeType>
</ns2:MultipleResponse>
```

I call my REST from a web GUI which is in Spring MVC.

I use jQuery to populate one select dropdown from the choise of another select dropdown. This works in Chrome but not in FF or IE.
I use Firebug in FF and it gives me this error:

> No elements were found with the selector: "AttributeType"

My jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = '<option value>Välj</option>';
    $('#serviceTypeAttributeGroup').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://server/project-web/services/rest/auth/v1_0/attributetypes/servicetypeattributegroup/" + $('#serviceTypeAttributeGroup').val(),
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).find("AttributeType").each(function() {
                    html = '';
                    var $attribute = $(this);
                    var id = $attribute.children("ID:first").text();
                    var name = $attribute.find("Name:first").text();
                    html += '<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>';
                    $('#attributeType').html(html);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#attributeType').html(html);
});
```

I have tried to change "`AttributeType`" to "`ns2:AttributeType`", "`ns2\\:AttributeType`" and "`ns2\:AttributeType`" but that doesn't change the error message in FF and the code stops working in Chrome.

When I look at the XML in FF it just shows plain text, if that's of any help? In Chrome I see all the tags.

My select dropdowns:

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="serviceTypeAttributeGroup"><s:message code="servicetypeattributegroup" />:</label></th>
    <td><sf:select path="serviceTypeAttributeGroup.ID" id="serviceTypeAttributeGroup">
        <sf:option value="0">&nbsp;</sf:option>
        <sf:options items="${listOfAttributeGroups}" itemLabel="attributeGroupType.name" itemValue="ID" />
    </sf:select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="attributeType"><s:message code="attributetype" />:</label></th>
    <td><sf:select path="attributeType.ID" id="attributeType">
        <sf:option value="0">&nbsp;</sf:option>
    </sf:select></td>
</tr>
```

Is there anyone who has an idea of what is wrong? ANd how I correct it?

Comment: You state that in firefox you see no tags. If so, then I'd start to suspect the data is not transmitted as XML at all so the problem may even originate from the server side and not the javascript. I'd put some logging on the server side to see what the request looks like when sent from chrome and when sent from Firefox; perhaps there is an important difference there that may be a clue.

Comment: That's right but today I see the tree structure and just a warning "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." But I'll check just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my jQuery to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var html = '';
        $('#serviceTypeAttributeGroup').change(function() {
            html = '';
            $.ajax({
                url: '<c:url value="/mvc/serviceTypeAttribute/attributeTypes" />',
                type: "GET",
                data: "id=" + $('#serviceTypeAttributeGroup').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))).each(function() {
                        html += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>';
                        $('#attributeType').html(html);
                    });
                }
            });
            $('#attributeType').html(html);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and created a method in my controller and now it's working in both Chrome and FF.

Thank you for your input guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to escape it like this:

```
$(data).find("ns2\\:AttributeType")
```

Comment: I've tried that, I see now that one of the \ disappeared in my post above. I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

most probably this line causes the problem

```
url: "http://server/project-web/services/rest/auth/v1_0/attributetypes/servicetypeattributegroup/" + $('#serviceTypeAttributeGroup').val(),
```

you should try with relative path instead of giving the compete path to the server. Otherwise some browsers will block because of **same origin policy**

Comment: If it is in the same domain it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Alvaro if he is browsing in https it makes the problem. right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Alvaro you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449627/javascript-absolute-path-to-url-works-on-one-page-but-creates-ajax-error-messag

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.
I still get the same error message in Firebug.

Comment: Isn't this a red herring? The error originates from the success handler, so the ajax request was successfully done.